# Объявление константного динамического массива

Tags: c++

Объявление массива как указателя отлично работает

```
class Test {
  char * const chars;
  Test(int cnt) : chars(new char[cnt]) {}
}
```

вопрос а можно ли как-то такой массив не как указатель, а как массив `[]`.

Вот так

```
class Test {
  const char chars[];
  Test(int cnt) : chars(new char[cnt]) {}
}
```

получаю ошибку

> error: flexible array member 'Test::chars' not at end of 'class QueryValues'
> const char  chars[];

Мне нужно чтобы повторное присвоение `chars = ...` вызывало ошибку, но при этом можно было изменять элементы массива

Comment: *Мне нужно чтобы повторное присвоение chars = ... вызывало ошибку, но при этом можно было изменять элементы массива*  - ну так оно так уже и сделано. *а можно ли как-то такой массив не как указатель, а как массив []* - нет

Comment: @user7860670 да. Вопрос в том можно ли заменить `*` на `[]`. Чтобы я сразу видел, что это не просто указатель, а массив

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412749/13970074

Comment: `[]` вместо `*`  можно использовать только в заголовках и прототипах функций (вроде только там)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы сразу видеть, что это будет массив, делайте так (и еще и ресурсы подчистяцаа):

```
#include <memory>

class Test {
  ::std::unique_ptr<char[]> const chars;
  Test(int cnt) : chars{new char[cnt]{}} {}
};
```